# WP_Query with custom post_type and cat retrieving unwanted posts with the custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

I have a custom post type "projets" that is using the category taxonomy (so it is sharing categories with regular posts).

When I call WP_Query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projets',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
```

It works perfectly fine.
But when I add a category to the arguments like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projets',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'cat' => 39
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
```

It does not returns only projets custom post_type but also regular posts that share the category 39...
Is there a way to make sure **only** the custom post type will be returned?

For info I use the [Custom Post Type UI](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) extension to declare the post type, I did not declare them myself.

---

**Edit:**

To clarify after the first comments, I did not register a custom taxonomy.

I only registered a custom post type called "projets" using the CPT UI plugin, with which I linked the Categories (WP Core) built-in taxonomy.

You can have a look at [this](https://ibb.co/37vDvPn) and [this](https://ibb.co/zrKQcG7) screenshots to see how I configured everything.

The post type name I am using with WP_Query is correct, since it does return the "projets" posts. The problem is that when I add a category to the $args, then regular posts (posts with the "post" type) are being returned.

---

**Edit 2 and solution:**

As pointed out by [@krzysiek-dróżdż](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/34172/krzysiek-dr%C3%B3%C5%BCd%C5%BC) and [@chinmoy-kumar-paul](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/57436/chinmoy-kumar-paul) , in my theme file I am using the pre_get_posts filter :

```
//Add projets custom posts within the loop
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( (is_category() || is_tag()) && $query->is_archive() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'projets'
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

If I comment it out, the problem is gone... So the problem is found out!

But isn't it a WordPress bug?  I mean I still do want this custom post type to be included in the loop, so my problem is not completely solved.

**In the end, one solution is to add `$args['suppress_filters'] = true;` before doing the query, allowing to avoid this filter and fix the problem.**

Comment: Have you registered native categories for "projets" CPT? Do you have any actions modifying query assigned to `pre_get_posts` hook?

Comment: Yes within the Custom Post Type UI plugin I linked the native categories with the "projet" CPT

Comment: Are you certain that the singular name for your CPT is "projets" and not "projet"? You need to use the singular name as your `post_type` argument.

Comment: @WebElaine not singular name, but slug, to be precise ;) Singular name is just a label. But it may be a good catch...

Comment: Yes sure, it's in the configuration, you can check the screenshots I made. I tried it anyway just to be sure, nothing returns, the slug / singular name is definitely "projets" (it works with my first query).

 It really is as I said: when 'cat' => 39 (or a tax_query) is used, it seems the "post_type" is ignored and all posts linked with the category are returned, without regarding their post_type

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I didn't pay enough attention to your first comment, the problem was linked to the pre_get_posts filter

Comment: @Pierre i thought so, because the part you’ve posted looked correct and it should work just fine...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż write an answer and you get the bounty

Comment: @Pierre Done, it's not the best answer, as written after problem is solved, but it should be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a CPT with slug `projets` and you've registered built-in categories for that CPT, it all looks correct.

So there are two possibilities, that I would check:

1. Typos - maybe you misstyped your CPT name somewhere in your code.
2. `pre_get_posts` filter is modifying your query and changing its behavior (it's pretty common if you write `pre_get_posts` and don't pay enough attention to conditions inside of it).

Comment: A call to `pre_get_posts` in my theme files was the culprit

Answer (score 2):

You will use the tax_query option for custom post type. So your query will be look like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'projets',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array( 39 )
        )
    ),
);
$projects = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, I already tried it with the tax_query and the result is the same. I tried nevertheless to copy / paste your code and got the same problem...

Comment: are you using any pre_get_posts hook in your theme file?

Comment: you're right, I am using it and commenting it fixes the problem... kind of, since if I comment this code out then the custom post isn't added to the loop anymore and will not appear in the "all posts" loop. Any idea?

Comment: I updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass CAT parameter for the custom taxonomy. you have to use tax_query.

Reference WordPress codex URL: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I think you can, it's working : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters but the problem is not here, maybe I didn't explain my problem correctly. The category selection is working, but the WP_Query does not returns only "projets" post types...

But anyway I tried with tax_query and the result is the same. Instead of having only posts with the post_type "projets", I also get posts with the post_type "post"

Comment: Well, of course you can. But it will make sense only if you register native categories for other CPTs.

Comment: Yes sure, but I think he has registered a custom post type.

Comment: So what? You can register built-in taxonomies for CPTs also...

Comment: Sorry, I mean custom taxonomy.

Comment: @Pierre please double check the registered custom post type, may be spell mistake, is it "projets"?

Comment: @JaydipNimavat I added some details to my question. I double checked spelling, configuration, and search and tried about everything I could fin on internet but so far no luck...